Cannot send email from shared host using Microsoft 365 email
I own a domain name - let's call it soze.com. It's with a shared host so I have cpanel as well as a shell, but not full root access obviously. My hosting provider (which uses Go Daddy) recently changed all their accounts to Microsoft 365 email which I did not want, but had no choice in the matter.
Since the change, I have not been able to send or receive emails from my domain. My primary email address - let's call it keyser@soze.com - will allow me to send emails from any connected email app (e.g. Outlook, webmail etc.), however the emails are never delivered to the recipient and no sending error is ever shown. Also, sending emails to this address simply disappear into the ether - no errors on the sending side.
There is one potential complication I should mention. I have had a Microsoft account using the email address keyser@soze.com for many years now, and have never had a problem logging into my Microsoft account using this address. My email account keyser@soze.com has also never had an issue previously. It seems this change to Microsoft 365 email may have caused the issue.
My primary question is: how can I figure out what's causing the sent/received emails to disappear? Is there some sort of email tracing tool I can use, or any tools/logs in cpanel that I can use? Or any Linux shell commands?
My secondary question is: should I change my Microsoft account to use a different email alias so as not to cause problems in future, or will this cause problems with any services I already use?

I think your best bet is to contact godaddy with this information and have them look into it.

@Silbee Thanks for the advice and I shall do so, but I thought it might be helpful to have some answers on here that deal with disappearing emails in general?

Problem is that you're not going to be seen as a private tenant by microsoft, so you likely arent able to use their admin panels to trace anything. I'm not familiar with CPanel, but a quick google search showed that it has a "Track Delivery" option under Email which might help. However i think the problem is going to be further up the chain and will be invisible to you.
